# Loss of privileges with bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I was wondering. I've received the privilege to set bounties. But since I'm still very low on reputation. If someone puts an answer that receives the bounty, will I also go back to that status privilege-wise, or will I keep those?

Comment: The Reputation is removed as soon as you set the bounty. If there is no suitable answer, the reputation will be lost anyway.

Comment: On the other hand, a bounty increases the visibility of your question. You might gain back some of the bounty cost as vote up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will keep any badges earned but will lose privileges if you drop below the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

For most situations, you can probably safely ignore the "bounty" feature.  It is a bit of a niche feature, and gaining the "privilege" to set a bounty does not mean that it will necessarily be all that useful to you to do so, in your everyday use of the site.